# How do I pass an array to another action in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I created a array in `start` for displaying the IDs one by one, and I want to the same array used in another action called `next`. In `start` I created a array called `ques`. I want to use `ques` in `next`.

START:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  def start
    @user = current_user
    @student = Student.find_by_admission_no(@user.username)
    @exam_group = ExamGroup.find_by_id(params[:exam_group_id])
    @answer = Answer.new(params[:ans])
    @module = params[:student_additional_field]
    @questions = shuf_order(@exam_group,@module)
    ques = []
    @questions.each do |a|
      ques.push q.id unless q.id.nil?
    end
    a = ques.first
    @s = 1
    @ans = Question.find_by_id(a)  
    render(:update) do |page|
      page.replace_html 'main', :partial => 'ans', :object => @ans
      page.replace_html 'quespan', :partial => 'ques'
    end
  end
```

Next:

```
def next
  @user = current_user
  @student = Student.find_by_admission_no(@user.username)
  @exam_group = ExamGroup.find_by_id(params[:exam_group_id])
  @answer = Answer.new(params[:ans])
  @answer.answer = params[:answer]
  @answer.exam_group_id = @exam_group.id
  @answer.user_id = @user.id
  passed_question = params[:passed_question]
  @answer.questions_id = passed_question
  @question = Question.find_by_id(passed_question)
  @module = Question.find_by_sql ["SELECT student_additional_field_id FROM questions WHERE id=#{passed_question}"]
  student_additional_field_id = @module[0].student_additional_field_id
  @questions = shuf_order(@exam_group,student_additional_field_id)
  a = @questions.first
  @answer.modules_id = student_additional_field_id
  if @answer.save
    @ans = Question.find_by_id(a, :conditions => [' id not in (?)',answered])
    unless @ans.nil?
      render(:update) do |page|
        page.replace_html 'main', :partial => 'ans', :object => @ans
      end
    else
      render(:update) do |page|
        page.replace_html 'main', :partial => 'ans2'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to pass variables between actions is the [flash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) variable.

In start:

```
flash[:ques] = []
flash[:ques].push 'whatever'
```

In next:

```
flash[:ques]
```

to access the saved var.

But in your case maybe you want to save your ques in session or DB to use `ques` in more than these 2 actions:

In start:

```
session[:ques] = []
session[:ques].push 'whatever'
```

In next:

```
session[:ques]
```

Or in DB, you maybe would need a new table.

Comment: is this method change for each login

Comment: one more thing i want to give an conditions to the array... for each execution of next flash question must be skip what i seen last